# Change http response code in angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs, apache, http-headers, ionic-framework

i need to change http response code from 200 to 404 in otherwise case of stateProvider

```
.state('app.notfound', {
    url: "not_found",
    cache: false,
    views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "/template/not_found.html",
      controller: "NotFoundCtrl"
    }
  }
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/not_found');
```

Normally notfound controller returns 200. How can i change response code?
Thanks

Comment: why does return code matter here?

Comment: Normally you use .otherwise() to redirect people because they routed to somewhere they shouldn't be. I can't ever imagine you want a 404.. Make a HTML page that looks like a 404, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set the HTTP Response code using client side programming. The Response code is send by the server, you only handle with the response as is, and are not permitted nor are you able to alter this.

Comment: Agreed. The response is provided by your service, not by AngularJS.